# AJAX - Update div content - Going backwards?

Tags: jquery, ajax

A current web based tool is template driven, rendering HTML and serving it a page at a time. I've been experimenting with using more modern tools such as ajax to load page contents, purely what changes between pages.

One problem I've discovered in testing is that if I a 'back' link (which calls `JavaScript:history.go(-1);` ) as with out current tool it doesn't work. In our previous system such links take you to the previous page (where one existed).

In the test system I'm updating div content using jQuerys ajax.

Does anyone have a strategy for working around this with dynamic content, providing a link which takes you back one step in a hierarchy?

Comment: You can use url hashtags (fragments)

Comment: This sort of hashtag? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_%28metadata%29#Hashtags If so I don't see how the can help in this situation

Comment: going to test some of the plugins mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with this problem many times, there are all sorts of solutions that recommend manipulating browser history and intercepting back clicks from the browser etc.

The short of it is that you use page parameters to control the content rendered on a page, however changing the address bar values will reload the page, so how does this work? Simple, you can change any value after a # and the browser will not reload the page. Then your javascript simply reads the value after the # to determine the content of the page.
[Here is a good article on it.](http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/content/fixing-the-back-button-and-enabling-bookmarking-for-ajax-apps/).

I wondered how gmail did it and analyzing their page it seems that they use a lot of `iframe`s. The advantage of iframes is that they can give your site an ajax look and feel without really being as such and I believe hitting back on a browser simply hits back on the iframe. It's been a while since I did something like this so can't be 100% sure.

I hope this helps. No one person here will be able to give you a 100% working solution (to the best of my knowledge) the nature of ajax applications is such that the solution has to be custom as well.

Answer (score 0):

The back link won't work because you are not loading the entire page (the URL does not change), but this is obvious.

Try out saving the user's history in a javascript-cookie and then just loading the page listed one unit above. That way, clicking on "back" wouldn't also allow to get back to an extern page they browsed before, what javascript:history.back() does.